# Con qué libreria o clase puedo leer un archivo de audio o video y extraer el tiempo de duracion y que lo pueda editar ( php )

Tags: php, javascript, json

No tengo codigo porque eso es lo que necesito por ejemplo yo estaba usando mp3Info que es una clase en php pero no me lee todos los archivos mp3 y los que me lee no me muestra el timepo correctamente exacto y que yo quiro leer tanto archivos de audio como de video de la mayoria de los formatos comunes y que pueda extraer el tiempo de duracion del video o audio para mostrar, guardar y editar los tiempos de duracion de cada unos de los archivos subidos. 
  Estoy creando algo parecido a lo de esta web https://gotranscript.com/upload/transcriptions

```
<?php

//directorio del la clase que estoy usando para generar los tiempos de los audios

include_once __DIR__ . "/src/Mp3Info.php";
use wapmorgan\Mp3Info\Mp3Info;


if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $fileId = $_POST;
    $name = $_FILES['files']['name'][0];
    $rutaDeLAudio = __DIR__ ."/update-unpaid-order/uploads/" . $name;
    if (file_exists($rutaDeLAudio)) {
        $ruta = '/gotranscript/gotranscript/gotranscript.com/upload/update-unpaid-order/uploads/' . $name;
    } else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0], $rutaDeLAudio)) {
        $ruta = '/gotranscript/gotranscript/gotranscript.com/upload/update-unpaid-order/uploads/' . $name;
    }

//llamada o intancia de la clase a usar para obtener los tiempos de los audios

    $audio = new Mp3Info($rutaDeLAudio, true);

//$audio->duration (me muestra el tiempo del audio en segundos)

$duration = ($audio->duration / 60);

//crar u id para cada unos de los audios que se suben simulando el id del la base de datos

$id = rand();

// un array que arroja al terminar el proceso para se usado para mostrar en pantalla

    $data = array('duration' => $duration, 'download' => $ruta,'original_duration' => $duration, 'comment' => '', 'original_filename' => $name, 'duration_for_humans' => $duration, 'from_human' => '00:00:00', 'till_human' => $duration, 'id'=> $id);

    exit(json_encode($data));
}
```

Comment: ¿Con este código tienes algún error o cuál es el problema que intentas resolver? - como no es clara tu pregunta, debes leer [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Luego [edit] la pregunta para que cualquiera que la lea, entienda el problema y pueda darte alguna solución.

Comment: Yo usaría ffmpeg (https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) y así poder hacer todo lo que quieras y de soporte ffmpeg, por ejemplo (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922925/php-ffmpeg-get-video-duration) aunque para ello, el servidor debe de tener la librería instalada.